# Page_Load is called multiple times if there is an exception in Page_Load

Tags: asp.net

I wrote the following code

```
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string data = Request.Form["postedData"];
                        if(someFunc(data))
                            Response.Redirect(SuccessURL, false);
                        else
                            Response.Redirect(FailureURL, false);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Response.Redirect(FailureURL, false);
                    }
                }
            }
```

It works fine unless there is an exception in the Page_Load. From my understanding the code should redirect the page to FailureURL in case of an exception. But in my case when there is an exception Page_Load gets called again and again with posted data as NULL. Any clue?

Comment: the someFunc(data) decodes it,then checks for some value. If the posted data is not a valid encoded string it will cause exception.

Comment: Are you handling the exception in someFunc, or simply re-throwing it?  Can you show the code for someFunc?

Comment: I am handling nothing.the only catch block is in the page_load.

Comment: @Raihan Alam: Are you certain that FailureURL is not the same page?

Comment: @Razen as I already mentioned it works fine if there is no exception.

Comment: @Raihan - if no exception is thrown, then you're redirecting to the `SuccessURL` - Razvan's question was wether or not `SuccessURL` and `FailureURL` point to the same page.  Without seeing more of your code, we really can't offer any suggestions.

Comment: @Tim FailureURL is not pointing to the same page for sure,if someFunc() returns False then it redirects to the proper place which is actually a sign out url.I am using the terms SuccessURL/FailureURL to look the code more generic so that someone can understand easily. For the same reason using the someFunc() to hide my own business. Is not it enough to know that this function caused an exception which is caught in the catch block?I tried to make it look as simple as possible,dont know why you are misunderstanding it.

Comment: @Raihan - Based on the code you've posted, what you have should work.  So something else is obviously going on, which is why the request for more information.  Remember, what may be simple and obvious to you, the person writing the code with the whole picture, may not be as simple and obvious to someone else looking at it without the whole picture.  That being said, if someFunc throws an error, is the error being caught in your catch block?

Comment: @Tim each time the execution is in the catch block I write the exception message in a file. so what I see is my file getting more and more entries :(

Comment: @Raihan - is it the same message?  What is the message or messages?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your redirect code to this:

**EDIT**: Added code to avoid ThreadAbortException

```
Response.Redirect(FailureURL, false); 
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But using true has a problem. The page then causes a ThreadAbort exception to close the current page execution. But still it may solve my issue, I will update after I have tried it.

Comment: @Raihan Alam: Edited my answer. Using this code will avoid ThreadAbortException.