# Async method in controller is called multiple times when an exception is caught

Tags: c#, ajax, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to troubleshoot a problem with exceptions not getting through to my ajax call properly.

My asynchronous controller method is called multiple times, where I only send one ajax request. The response is supposed to be sent, but looking at the network tab in firefox's debug panel, I see no response; the ajax error handler function also has a readyState = 0. This happens only when an exception is thrown inside the async controller method.

There are three/four parts to this problem:

- My javascript
- My async controller method
- The async private controller method called by the latter
- The JsonError and JsonSuccess methods formatting the response

Ajax call:

```
function test() {

    var data = {
        campagneId: 15,
        tiersNum: 2721
    };

    console.debug("Starting Ajax !");

    $.ajax({
        url: "/CampagnesMailing/SendMail",
        data: data,
        method: "POST",
        success: function (response) {
            console.debug("Sent mail successfully!");
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOpt, thrownError) {
            console.error("Error!");
            console.error(xhr); //xhr.readyState is 0
            console.error(ajaxOpt);
            console.error(thrownError); //this is empty
        },
        complete: function () {
            console.debug("Finished ajax call!");
        }
    });
}
$("#goButton").on("click", test);
```

Async controller method called by ajax:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> SendMail(int campagneId, int tiersNum)
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage mail = await GetMailFor(campagneId, tiersNum); //I tried adding .ConfigureAwait(false) with no change
        return JsonSuccess();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return JsonError(e);
    }
}
```

Async method GetMailFor:

```
private async Task<MailMessage> GetMailFor(int campagneId, int tiersNum)
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("")); // This throws an ArgumentException

        return mail;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

JsonError / JsonSuccess:

```
protected JsonResult JsonSuccess()
{
    Response.StatusCode = (int) System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
    Response.StatusDescription = "SUCCESS";
    return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
protected JsonResult JsonError(Exception e)
{
    Response.StatusCode = (int) System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    Response.StatusDescription = e.Message;
    //HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    return Json(new {e.Message}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

When I put a breakpoint on the first line of SendMail (the one with `MailMessage mail = await GetMailFor(campagneId, tiersNum);`) and a breakpoint in the catch, I see the method is called 7 times and goes into the catch everytime, mostly with different `ManagedThreadId` values in `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread`.

Oddly enough, if I replace the `mail.To.Add()` call by a `throw new ArgumentException("Boom");`, the process goes well and only one call is caught in my breakpoints.

I had a look at [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7172270/1151654) but adding `HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();` before `return Json(new {e.Message}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` did not change anything.

I only see 1 POST request in Network tab from firefox. This never gets any response.
Please note these snippets are enough to cause the problem but I use more code in the real application (No need to warn me about async method containing no await).

What is happening? Why is SendMail called 7 times? Why only when `new MailAddress()` throws and not when I throw manually? How can I debug such a mindblowing behavior?

**EDIT:** Removing try/catch from inside the `GetMailFor` method yields no change.
**EDIT2:** Removing any mention of `async`, `Task<T>` or `await` also yields no change, so this has nothing to do with an `async` problem. I'm kind of lost now because I don't know how to debug that...
**EDIT3:** I never enter the `Application_Error` function, but I enter `Application_BeginRequest` everytime before entering `SendMail` and `Application_EndRequest` everytime after returning `JsonError`

Comment: Is this an MVC or WebAPI controller?

Comment: MVC, sorry I forgot to tag it.

Comment: I don't see why any of this is `async`?

Comment: why wrapping `SendMail` AND `GetMailFor` in `try/catch`?

Comment: The first thing I would try is to remove the aysnc from the controller action to see if it makes any difference, I have found exception can get swallowed by async methods.

Comment: @DavidG please see my edit: This is a short snippet to lighten the code to find the problem. This reproduces the same problem so it's fine. In the "real" code i'm trying to write I have async calls to EntityFramework repositories.

Comment: @FlorianGl I tried things. I had the same problem with no try/catch in GetMailFor

Comment: @BenRobinson yeah, I'll try that but in the real code I do need those to be async

Comment: @Eregrith You might find removing aysnc allows you to debug and solve the underlying problem, you can then make it async again when you have it all working.

Comment: @BenRobinson I think the problem comes from async itself. Why else would the method be called 7 times? :/  
I just tried removing try/catch in `GetMailFor` and all async/Task<T> from `SendMail` and `GetMailFor` and the breakpoints are activated multiple times (apparently alternating ManagedThreadId between two values), so there might be a problem somewhere else indeed... How do I find the problem now? There is no stack trace except my `SendMail` and "external code"

Comment: I've peered through `Application_BeginRequest` and `Application_EndRequest`. The `HttpContext.Current.Response` is correctly set in `EndRequest` but immediately after it returns, I fall back into `BeginRequest`. There is no `RedirectPath` in `Response`.

Comment: are you sure the problem isn't in your js code? maybe you are creating an infinite loop by accident if the ajax call fails...

Comment: @FlorianGl I check the Network tab in my browser debug panel and only one POST request is sent. It seems I have found the problem: The exception message set as `Response.StatusDescription` contained a newline which broke the request flow. I am posting an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying crazy things at random, I stumbled upon the real problem: `JsonError` was adding the exception message as `Response.StatusDescription` while the message contained `\r\n`. This somehow broke the request handling.

The fix is simply to change `JsonError` to:

```
protected JsonResult JsonError(Exception e)
{
    Response.StatusCode = (int) System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    Response.StatusDescription = e.Message.Replace("\r\n", " | ");
    return Json(new {e.Message}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I figured if the problem does not happen when I throw manually, it must reside in the differences between the `ArgumentException` I throw and the one thrown by `new MailAddress("");`. Saw the `\r\n` and thought "Hmm... that would be awful if that did something..."

Comment: Makes sense...now we just have to wait for Jon Skeet to explain why `"\r\n"` breaks the request handling^^

Comment: Is there any document or bug link relate to this issue ? Why do "\r\n" break the request handling ? Btw, you save my day.